# sfdc-styleguide usage questions in Salesforce1

Tags: css, salesforce1-app, sfdc-styleguide

I am trying to follow http://sfdc-styleguide.herokuapp.com/ 's usage of components and style classes. I have been unable to find references to any of the style classes described in the component section. A concise example of this to look at is the progress spinner.

The progress spinner on sfdc-styleguide specs:

```
<div class="tc">
  <img src="assets/loading-gray.gif" alt="loading" class="sq-20 dib">
</div>
```

While looking at one/one.app I see

```
<div class=" indicato forceLoadingIndicator oneCenterStage " role="alert" data-aura-rendered-by="803:1.1">
  <img class="loading large uiImage" alt="Loading" src="/auraFW/resources/aura/s.gif" data-aura-rendered-by="807:1.1">
</div>
```

where the actual loader image is defined in the app.css stylesheet as a `background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64string)`

While I understand the efficiency of using the base64 string over a separate resource, none of the other classes really line up. For example, there is no sq-20 or tc class in any stylesheet I can find within the actual SF1 app or a custom VF iFrame.

This seems to occur across all of the components mentioned in the sfdc-styleguide that I have checked (list, lookup, progress indicator).

Has anyone had better luck with this (maybe I missed an include somewhere?) Did I misinterpret the purpose of this guide, I thought it pointed out existing classes that would be included in SF1 somehow and we could take advantage of. Are we supposed to just rip off the stylesheet assets from this guide and include them or otherwise land near their look?

Comment: I doubt they want us to "rip off", since presumably they want to have our app look like it belongs in S1, even if S1 changes its style guide. I'm honestly not sure *what* they were thinking. They're definitely taking a "microsoft" approach to this, though, except Microsoft was nice enough to include their metrics directly in one document/stylesheet.

Comment: I've tweeted this question and mentioned SalesforceUX.

Comment: The only guidance I have received on this from SF thus far is to copy all of the style guide resources (css, images) into my custom VF page. Aka the "rip off" solution :)

Comment: I also received guidance that we are not licensed to use the Proxima Nova Soft font within our custom VF page, displayed in SF1, without obtaining our own licensing. SF1 font licensing does not cascade down to custom VF pages meant to be displayed within SF1. Costs anywhere between $29 and $29x4 depending on how many typefaces you need.

Comment: @MikeTetlow In other words, virtually every non-ISV customer will end up violating the licensing, and many ISVs will be unaware of this and also be in violation. Completely irresponsible. SF should buy a perpetual use license for their platform, similar to what Microsoft provides with every copy of Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone at the foundation did all the dirty work: https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/bootstrap-sf1

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you need to take whatever assets you need and use them as opposed to referencing some sort of "published" styles.  From the [Salesforce1 App Developer Guide's **Visual Design Considerations** section](http://docs.developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.186.0.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices_design_considerations.htm):

> Directly referencing Salesforce1 style sheets in your pages, or
>   depending on styles found in them, isn’t supported. As Salesforce1
>   evolves, the styles will change in ways that you won’t expect. Pages
>   that depend on unsupported styles may eventually break.

Answer (score 0):

> one alternate to directly pasting will be using one starter library from Josh.
>   https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/03/styling-for-salesforce1-mobile-with-the-onestarter-jquery-plugin.html

You can include CSS and JS libraries and reference from static resource .That will solve the problem of directly referencing the CSS styling in the app guide

Comment: One starter is great. I have found that this is a bit more what I was looking for: https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/bootstrap-sf1